# Convert Slash To Underscore Using URI Routing

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I'm creating routes in my applications and I was wondering if it can convert the slash in the url to underscore in my api.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

> http://www.example.dev/api/v1/test/supertest.json?id=7&test=whatever

In my routes it has to be interpreted like:

> http://www.example.dev/api/test_supertest/format/json?id=7&test=whatever

I succeed about the format and version but not about `test_supertest`

Here is my actual route :

```
$route['api/'.config_item('rest_api_version').'/(:any)'.'(/.*)'.'(\.:any)'.'(:any)'] = 'api/$1_$2$4&format=$3';
```

How do I convert the slashes to underscores?

Comment: I'm assuming `supertest` being converted to `superstuff` is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Route:**

```
$route['api/' . config_item('rest_api_version') . '/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.([^?]+)\?(:any)'] = 'api/$1_$2/format/$3?$4';
```

**Regex Breakdown:**

1. `api/' . config_item('rest_api_version') . '/` match API version
2. `([^/]+)` match 1 or more characters that are not a `/`
3. `/` match a `/`
4. `([^.]+)` match 1 or more characters that are not a `.`
5. `\.` match a `.`
6. `([^?]+)` match 1 or more characters that are not a `?`
7. `\?` match a `?`
8. `(:any)` match any character

**Replace Breakdown:**

`api/$1_$2/format/$3?$4`

`$1` is replaced with match from above list item 2

`$2` is replaced with match from above list item 4

`$3` is replaced with match from above list item 6

`$4` is replaced with match from above list item 8

**Result:**

> http://www.example.dev/api/v1/test/supertest.json?id=7&test=whatever

Becomes

> http://www.example.dev/api/test_supertest/format/json?id=7&test=whatever

Comment: That is really strange, I have this route builded: 
DEBUG - 10-04-2013 13:55:38 --> Redirecting to : api/v1.0/test/supertest.json  --> api/test_supertestn&format=jso

Comment: why the n from json is after supertest oO this is really weird

Comment: @Simon not sure what is causing it, but try the above edited answer. I'm hoping explicitly matching the `?` will fix it since it appears that the `?` is being match with the last char from the file extension.

Comment: I tried again and again since one hour and didn't figure it out with your route, anyway, I succeed and changed the routes a lil'bit and it works !

Comment: Finale route : $route['api/' . config_item('rest_api_version') . '/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.([^?]+)\?(:any)'] = 'api/$1_$2/format/$3?$4'; <== Edit your answer and I'm going to validate it.

Comment: Thans you again @cryptic for the help :) Really useful.